# Setting (desktop-save-mode t) in init file calls (desktop-read) immediately when starting Emacs in daemon mode. How to avoid?

Tags: frames, emacs-daemon, desktop, session

Previously, I used GUI Emacs, everything worked perfectly - the desktop was saved and restored as it should be.

I decided to try Emacs in daemon mode. First I made changes to the init.el file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(desktop-load-locked-desktop t) 
 '(desktop-path '("~/.emacs.d/"))
 '(desktop-save-mode t)
 '(save-place-mode t)
 '(tab-bar-mode t))
```

```
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook 'desktop-read)
```

Then started the server

```
  Start Init ...
  Loading desktop...done
  Loading saveplace...done
  Wrote /home/mocambo/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop.lock
  Desktop: 1 frame, 1 buffer restored.
  Starting Emacs daemon.
  Inside after-make-frame-functions
  Not reloading the desktop; already loaded
  Inside server-after-make-frame-hook
  Not reloading the desktop; already loaded
  When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0
```

EDIT:
By adding some debug messages to the init file, it turned out that Emacs loads the desktop earlier than it should.

The culprit may be the `(desktop-save-mode t)` in the init file. Once set, Emacs calls `(desktop-read)`. How to avoid it? The next time I save the settings, the `(desktop-save-mode t )` init file reappears.

Temporary solution:

```
(custom-set-variables
...
;; '(desktop-save-mode t)
...)
```

Comment: Is there actually a problem?  "When Desktop Save mode is enabled ... The next time Emacs starts, if this mode is active it will restore the desktop."  All I'm seeing in your logs is Emacs refraining from doing that *more than once*.

Comment: Calling `desktop-read` in `server-after-make-frame-hook` sounds slightly mad, btw.  Why would you do that?

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the customized user option from your init file, then use `M-x customize-option` and use the "Revert" button to "erase customizations".

Comment: I just want to restore frame from previous desktop session. I have `(desktop-save-mode t)` setting in `init.el`. When I start `emacsclient -c`, it doesnt restore frame. I did as the [GNU Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) suggested - calling `desktop-read` from `server-after-make-frame-hook`. And this works only when I'll comment out the original `(desktop-save-mode t)`.

Comment: Oh, interesting that it recommends doing that; thanks.  I can see the explanation for that in the manual page you linked.  So if you erase the customisation for the variable, is everything working the way you want?

Comment: If the problem is then that the desktop file doesn't get updated, I suggest you change your custom function to call `(desktop-save-mode 1)` after it calls `(desktop-read)`.  If you do that (and have gotten rid of the customized variable) then I suspect the sequence will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the `desktop.el` file and saw that `after-init-hook` contains a function where automatic `(desktop-read)` is called when `(desktop-save-mode t)` and `command-line-args` contains a no `--no-desktop` switch. So, to control `(desktop-read)` and to restore the desktop in `emacs --daemon` mode, you have to use the `--no-desktop` switch. :)